# Programmatically get ModelState from Gazebo

Tags: ros, gazebo, pr2, publisher

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,  I am trying to programmatically get information about the pose of a PR2 in Gazebo.   The examples on the wiki seem to be based upon command line using rosservice.  Based upon the Publisher/Subscriber example on the ROS wiki I would imagine it would be something like:

rospy.Subscriber("gazebo/model_states", Pose, callback)

but when I try something similar to this Gazebo sends and error msg and breaks the connection.  I would think it is just finding the right combination of topic and msg but I am having troubles figuring that out.  Any help would be appreciate.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9783/programmatically-get-modelstate-from-gazebo/) by [IanAlden](https://answers.ros.org/users/448/ianalden/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2011-04-20

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

gazebo expects a [ModelStates](http://www.ros.org/doc/api/gazebo/html/msg/ModelStates.html) topic, not Pose, try changing your callback to accept ModelStates and see if it fixes the issue.  To access the returned variables, please take a look at the following python service client example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import roslib; roslib.load_manifest('gazebo')

import sys

import rospy
from gazebo.srv import *

def gms_client(model_name,relative_entity_name):
    rospy.wait_for_service('/gazebo/get_model_state')
    try:
        gms = rospy.ServiceProxy('/gazebo/get_model_state', GetModelState)
        resp1 = gms(model_name,relative_entity_name)
        return resp1
    except rospy.ServiceException, e:
        print "Service call failed: %s"%e


def usage():
    return "%s [model_name] [relative_entity_name]"%sys.argv[0]

if __name__ == "__main__":
    if len(sys.argv) == 3:
        model_name = sys.argv[1]
        relative_entity_name = sys.argv[2]
    else:
        print usage()
        sys.exit(1)
    res = gms_client(model_name,relative_entity_name)
    print "returnd x position ",res.pose.position.x
```

---

Originally posted by [hsu](https://answers.ros.org/users/91/hsu/) with karma: 5780 on 2011-04-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [szokei](https://answers.ros.org/users/178/szokei/) on 2011-05-12**:
My objective is to synchronize the position of the robot in Gazebo and RViz. My node is controlling the robot's position through move_base node while in RViz the robot is remaining in the origin. I'm using this service client with the "gplane robot_description::base_footprint" arguments, how I could modify this client code(and which parameters to set) in order to update the pose in RVIz. Thank you!